# Emacs - how to avoid or replace wrong character encodings?

Tags: emacs, encoding, utf-8, ms-word, dos

Assume that I receive a Spanish text written in MS word and saved as plain text (.txt). Unfortunately, all the Spanish accents show up like this:

```
Un \372ltimo an\341lisis
```

Can anybody tell me how I can avoid this, or at least how I can replace these characters? They are simply not found by the replace-regexp-functions, otherwise I could write a little elisp function that replaces every occurence of them by the associated Spanish accented character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1) encoding.

Visit the file with that coding system instead. If Emacs does not automatically identify the coding system, you can revisit the file with an explicit coding system with `revert-buffer-with-coding-system` (`C-x RET r`).

For example, if you are looking at the garbled file you describe,

```
C-x RET r
latin-1 RET
yes RET
```

Then you can set the coding system you want for saving (`C-x RET f`) and specifying something like `utf-8`.

Comment: Great, thank you, that works and will save me a lot of work. The only 'thing' not recognized was \223reglamentada\224, but since the word is complete, I guess its some kind of formatting code from MS Word.

Comment: PS How does Emacs recognize such 'characters' like \372 or \341? How could I do a regexp search in a buffer and find them?

Comment: `\372` is a single character (octal 372) which is `ú` in Latin-1. Since it means nothing in UTF-8, emacs will display the byte value instead.

Comment: \223 and \224 seem to be recognised if you use `windows-1250` instead of `latin-1`.