# How to display non-ascii in emacs?

Tags: emacs, non-ascii-characters

I am looking at text files of Portuguese words in firefox, and I see accented characters correctly, but when I download the text files and open them in emacs, I see n\372mero (which is número), rela\347\343o (which is relação), and so on. What needs to be done to display the words correctly in emacs?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11073003/113848).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system`.  It looks like the file is in `latin-1`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked when I chose latin-1-unix. But when I reopen it, it again shows me \347 etc. Can I not make the change permanent? I tried making some change (after running the above command) and saving the file, but when I reopen it, it is still as before.

Comment: Now it works after saving it as suggested in the other question.